# Python POST request can't find data attribute

Tags: python, django, post

I'm trying to write a POST request to my Django REST API in Python, but it can't seem to find an attribute in the data section of the request. Here's the function that handles the request:

```
 def post(self, request, id, format=None):
    obj = self.get_object_or_404(id)

    operation = request.POST.get('operation', None)
    if operation == None:
        print "Operation was none, uh oh."
        return Response()
    else:
        print "It worked!"
        return Response()
```

Now here's a POST ajax call in jquery. This one works. (Prints "It worked!")

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Token ' + token)},
  url: url,
  data: {
    'operation':-1,
  },
  success: callback,
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Now here's the POST call in Python, or my attempt at it. The "url" and "token" variables are exactly the same:

```
import json
import requests

url = <Same URL as above>
token = <same token as above>

data = {
    'operation' : -1,
}
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Token " + token,
}
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

This python requests does not work -- the app api prints "Operation was none, uh oh." Why would this happen? Am I not passing my data parameter correctly in the request?

EDIT: Solved. Don't call json_dumps on the data, just pass it in as is.

Comment: Why are you doing `json.dumps(data)`? Try just passing the `data=data`...

Comment: AH! Thank you, that worked. I was doing that because some other tutorial said you needed to encode your data via json before making a post request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need your `data` to be JSON encoded, as you're not doing anything with JSON in your view. Simply pass your dictionary directly to `data`:

```
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```